# Telerik AppBuilder extension for Visual Studio does not have UI Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, telerik, telerik-appbuilder

I looking for developing hybrid Kendu UI mobile apps using visual studio 2012. When i downloaded and installed the app builder,  there is no UI designer view for the HTML. How can we design the HTML for appropriate layout without designer.

Looking forward your valuable reply...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Kendo UI visual Designer, you can use the AppBuilder in-browser client or the native Windows client. You can initiate a project with either of those tools, sync the code with your source control provider (git-based), and then continue development with Visual Studio.